# Close or Release my DataReader or SqlConnection

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqldatareader, sqlconnection, datareader

I have the following code to retrieve column names from a table

```or-tag-here
conn.Open()
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(colQuery, conn))
    {
        try
        {
            using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dr.Read();

                    var columns = new List<string>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        string colName = dr.GetName(i);
                        columns.Add(dr.GetName(i));
                        repColsString += colName;
                    }                   
                }
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append(ex.Message);
            }
```

I've tried using conn.Close() to close the connection but 'Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.' gets returned.

Or the connection times out with 'Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 15, Token : 0'  00:00:31.1460115

How do I properly close this connection and move out of the using block?

Comment: Add the using block to your SqlConnection, remove all close calls and you should be fine

Comment: the using block is the right way to do this.  one thing missing:

Comment: @Steve so wrap everything in   using(conn.Open()){...}?

Comment: @user1443098 is that one thing what Steve mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General structure:

```
using conn = new SqlConnection(...) {
    conn.Open();
    using cmd = new SqlCommand(conn) {
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.read) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How long should it take to close the connection?  It is taking nearly 15 to exit the using block.

Comment: depends on what's in "do stuff" .  could be milliseconds or days

Comment: It's only what is in the above code block.  Iterating through column names.  Does it depend on table size?

Comment: yes, it would, as written.  Looks like you want the table schema. the ExecuteReader option CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly can get you that.  Then you don't need the while loop